# Compare files that are in directory 1 but not directory 2?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ls, diff

I'm having trouble with a bash script I want to make

I know ls will list files that are in a directory but I want it to list directories that are in directory1 but NOT in directory2, and then list files in directory2 that are NOT in directory1.

In a feeble attempt, I tried:

```
ls -al | diff directory1 directory2
```

Quickly I realized why it didn't work. Can anyone help out a total bash nerd out?

Answer (score 9):

Given bash, this might be easiest as

```
$ comm <(ls -a dir1) <(ls -a dir2)
```

The `<(command)` expression runs *command* over a pipe and substitutes a `/dev/fd` reference:

```
mress:10018 Z$ echo <(ls)
/dev/fd/11
```

So the command above runs `ls -a` on each directory and feeds their outputs as file arguments to `comm`, which outputs up to 3 columns, tab-indented:  entries only in the first, entries in both, entries in the second.  (That is, if it's in both then it is indented by a tab, if it's only in the second it's indented by 2 tabs.)  You can also suppress columns by number:  `comm -1 foo bar` displays only the lines in both and lines in the second file, the latter indented by *one* tab.  (This is most commonly used by suppressing all but the column you want:  `comm -13 foo bar` shows only the lines in common.)

Given that you want those in the first directory, that translates to

```
$ comm -23 <(ls -a dir1) <(ls -a dir2)
```

If you need more than just whether it is present, use `diff -r`, which will output diffs for the files in common and a one-line message for files found only in one or the other.

Comment: `ls` will come with all problems with white space, tabs, linefeeds, backspaces and such in filenames.

Comment: The only one that will confound this is newlines, and I'd argue you have problems anyway in that case.  :)  If you're paranoid, use `ls -b`.

Comment: Not with find, do I?

Comment: Depends on what you're invoking with `find`.  But my main complaint about `find` is that it's a really heavy sledgehammer to swat what is usually a rather small fly.

Comment: Thanks! That works but can I get it to output the contents that are in file b that are NOT in file a without using 'comm'?

Comment: Also, what is /dev/fd/11?

Comment: See the discussion of `comm` options in my answer.  That would be `comm -12` (suppress column 1/in first file and column 2/in both files).

Comment: I cannot use 'comm'.

Comment: That was just demonstrating how the `<(command)` stuff worked.  `/dev/fd` is a way to refer to file *descriptors* with file *names*.  For example, `stdin` is `/dev/fd/0`.  So when `bash` sees the `<(ls -a dir1)` it creates a pipe, runs `ls` with its `stdout` connected to the write end, notes that the read end is its file descriptor 11, and passes `/dev/fd/11` as the "file" for `comm` to read from.

Comment: If you can't use `comm`, what *can* you use?  (You probably should have mentioned that in your question.)

Comment: Probably haha. Using comm worked perfectly but is there another way to provide the same output?

Comment: Sure.  You can duplicate it in a script or program in the language of your choosing, or you can use `diff -r` and `grep` out the "exists only in" messages.  Or any number of other ways; but I'd have to know what ways you can use before I could give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: @geekosaur: you might have noticed that I use `test` together with find. Which program would you expect to fail when invoked with 'find' and why?

Comment: @user unknown: Shell scripts with broken quoting, mostly.

Comment: So effectively you don't have any concrete example?

Comment: I'm failing to understand your hostility.  Did the phrasing of my original answer upset you?

Comment: +1 Awesome tool - This is going into my .bash_aliases ASAP.

Comment: Hey, I can use anything in here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20930447/index.html

Comment: Wow, that's pretty sorry.  You can use the `find` version, or `diff -qr dir1 dir2 | grep '^Only in '` (which will probably require further editing if you're using it in a script, and is *not* whitespace-safe).  And recommend to your VPS vendor that they provide useful tools.

Comment: I just want to add that this is amazing and I don't know how I'd never heard of either `comm` or the FD redirection trick until today.

Answer (score 4):

And here a pure script. These are the directories a and b:

```
find a b
a
a/a
a/b
a/c
a/f
a/f/h
a/f/i
b
b/b
b/c
b/d
b/f
b/f/g
b/f/h
```

Here is the command:

```
cd a
find ./ -exec test ! -e ../b/{} ";" -print
```

output:

```
./a
./f/i
```

Swap a and b for files in a but not in b. 
The ! is a negation. -e tests for -existance. In prosa: "Test if not exists the file found in a in ../b".

Note: You have to dive into a first, to get names without 'a'. For the second comparison you have to cd `../b`.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a graphical tool, use

```
xxdiff dir1 dir2
```

you might need to install it first. Similar programs are

```
gtkdiff
tkdiff
```

The midnight commander has a `compare directories` command build in, which works nice, if you don't go for subdirs.

Comment: No, I am not looking for a graphical tool, thank though!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the neglected `join` command.  Here some setup for two example directories, d1/ and d2/, each of which has some files with names unique to the directory, and some files with names in common with the other directory. This is only an example, so I used single-letter file names to illustrate file names unique to one or the other, and file names in common.

```
# set up for example
mkdir d1 d2
for name in a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
do
    touch d1/$name
done
for name in e f g h i j k l
do
    touch d2/$name
done

ls -1 d1 > d1.out   # That's "minus one" not "minus ell"
ls -1 d2 > d2.out
join d1.out d2.out       # files common to both d1/ and d2/
join -v 1 d1.out d2.out  # files only in directory d1/
join -v 2 d1.out d2.out  # files only in directory d2/
```

For me, it shows files like this:

```
 5:51PM 100 % join d1.out d2.out
e
f
g
h
 5:51PM 101 % join -v 1 d1.out d2.out
a
b
c
d
 5:52PM 102 % join -v 2 d1.out d2.out
i
j
k
l
```

UPDATE: You'd want to do different things in real life to accomodate files with whitespace in them, as `join` uses the first field "delimited by whitespace" to decide which lines are uniqe and which lines are common.

Comment: You should test your program with a file called "d2/f ". Rule of thumb: Nearly never use ls in scripts.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  Should d2/ only have one file, d2/f?  Because I tried this, and it works as expected.

Comment: I think he is concerned about filenames that include spaces (or tabs, since both are default input field delimiters for *join*). Maybe `join -t ''` (no delimiter) would help that case.

Comment: Yes, it isn't `d2/f` but `d2/f `. Tabs and newlines in filenames are rare, but allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` and `awk` to solve this.

With following layout:

```
$ mkdir a b a/1 b/1 b/2 a/3
$ touch a/f1 b/f1 a/f2 b/f3
```

Part one:

```
$ find a b -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | \
    awk -F/ ' { if (!w[$1]) w[$1]=++i; if (w[$1]>1) b[$2]=1; else a[$2]=1; }
          END { for (x in a) if (!b[x]) print x }'
3
```

Part two:

```
$ find b a -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | \
    awk -F/ ' { if (!w[$1]) w[$1]=++i; if (w[$1]>1) b[$2]=1; else a[$2]=1; }
          END { for (x in a) if (!b[x]) print x }'
f3
```

This compares to a `comm` solution:

```
$ comm -23 <(ls a) <(ls b)    
3
f2
$ comm -13 <(ls a) <(ls b)
2
f3
```

And to a `join` solution:

```
$ join -v1 <(ls a) <(ls b)
3
f2
$ join -v2 <(ls a) <(ls b)
2
f3
```

Answer (score 0):

use my functions:

```
setColors ()
{
# http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes
set -a
which printf >/dev/null 2>&1 && print=printf || print=print # Mandriva doesn't know about printf

hide='eval tput civis'
show='eval tput cnorm'
CLS=$(tput clear)
bel=$(tput bel)

case ${UNAME} in
AIX)
# text / foreground
N=$(${print} '\033[1;30m')
n=$(${print} '\033[0;30m')
R=$(${print} '\033[1;31m')
r=$(${print} '\033[0;31m')
G=$(${print} '\033[1;32m')
g=$(${print} '\033[0;32m')
Y=$(${print} '\033[1;33m')
y=$(${print} '\033[0;33m')
B=$(${print} '\033[1;34m')
b=$(${print} '\033[0;34m')
M=$(${print} '\033[1;35m')
m=$(${print} '\033[0;35m')
C=$(${print} '\033[1;36m')
c=$(${print} '\033[0;36m')
W=$(${print} '\033[1;37m')
w=$(${print} '\033[0;37m')
END=$(${print} '\033[0m')

# background
RN=$(${print} '\033[6;40m')
Rn=$(${print} '\033[40m')
RR=$(${print} '\033[6;41m')
Rr=$(${print} '\033[41m')
RG=$(${print} '\033[6;42m')
Rg=$(${print} '\033[42m')
RY=$(${print} '\033[6;43m')
Ry=$(${print} '\033[43m')
RB=$(${print} '\033[6;44m')
Rb=$(${print} '\033[44m')
RM=$(${print} '\033[6;45m')
Rm=$(${print} '\033[45m')
RC=$(${print} '\033[6;46m')
Rc=$(${print} '\033[46m')
RW=$(${print} '\033[6;47m')
Rw=$(${print} '\033[47m')

HIGH=$(tput bold)
SMUL=$(tput smul)
RMUL=$(tput rmul)
BLINK=$(tput blink)
REVERSE=$(tput smso)
REVERSO=$(tput rmso)
;;
*)
# text / foreground
n=$(tput setaf 0)
r=$(tput setaf 1)
g=$(tput setaf 2)
y=$(tput setaf 3)
b=$(tput setaf 4)
m=$(tput setaf 5)
c=$(tput setaf 6)
w=$(tput setaf 7)
N=$(tput setaf 8)
R=$(tput setaf 9)
G=$(tput setaf 10)
Y=$(tput setaf 11)
B=$(tput setaf 12)
M=$(tput setaf 13)
C=$(tput setaf 14)
W=$(tput setaf 15)
END=$(tput sgr0)

HIGH=$(tput bold)
SMUL=$(tput smul)
RMUL=$(tput rmul)
BLINK=$(tput blink)
REVERSE=$(tput smso)
REVERSO=$(tput rmso)

# background
Rn=$(tput setab 0)
Rr=$(tput setab 1)
Rg=$(tput setab 2)
Ry=$(tput setab 3)
Rb=$(tput setab 4)
Rm=$(tput setab 5)
Rc=$(tput setab 6)
Rw=$(tput setab 7)
RN=$(tput setab 8)
RR=$(tput setab 9)
RG=$(tput setab 10)
RY=$(tput setab 11)
RB=$(tput setab 12)
RM=$(tput setab 13)
RC=$(tput setab 14)
RW=$(tput setab 15)
;;
esac

BLUEf="${B}"
BLUE="${b}"
REDf="${R}"
RED="${r}"
GREENf="${G}"
GREEN="${g}"
YELLOWf="${Y}"
YELLOW="${y}"
MANGENTAf="${M}"
MANGENTA="${m}"
WHITEf="${W}"
WHITE="${w}"
CYANf="${C}"
CYAN="${c}"

OK="${RG}${n}OK${END}"
KO="${RR}${n}KO${END}"
NA="${N}NA${END}"

COLORIZE='eval sed -e "s/{END}/${END}/g" -e "s/{HIGH}/${HIGH}/g" -e "s/{SMUL}/${SMUL}/g" -e "s/{RMUL}/${RMUL}/g" -e "s/{BLINK}/${BLINK}/g" -e "s/{REVERSE}/${REVERSE}/g" -e "s/{REVERSO}/${REVERSO}/g"'
LOWS=' -e "s/{n}/${n}/g" -e "s/{r}/${r}/g" -e "s/{g}/${g}/g" -e "s/{y}/${y}/g" -e "s/{b}/${b}/g" -e "s/{m}/${m}/g" -e "s/{c}/${c}/g" -e "s/{w}/${w}/g"'
HIGHS=' -e "s/{N}/${N}/g" -e "s/{R}/${R}/g" -e "s/{G}/${G}/g" -e "s/{Y}/${Y}/g" -e "s/{B}/${B}/g" -e "s/{M}/${M}/g" -e "s/{C}/${C}/g" -e "s/{W}/${W}/g"'
REVLOWS=' -e "s/{Rn}/${Rn}/g" -e "s/{Rr}/${Rr}/g" -e "s/{Rg}/${Rg}/g" -e "s/{Ry}/${Ry}/g" -e "s/{Rb}/${Rb}/g" -e "s/{Rm}/${Rm}/g" -e "s/{Rc}/${Rc}/g" -e "s/{Rw}/${Rw}/g"'
REVHIGHS=' -e "s/{RN}/${RN}/g" -e "s/{RR}/${RR}/g" -e "s/{RG}/${RG}/g" -e "s/{RY}/${RY}/g" -e "s/{RB}/${RB}/g" -e "s/{RM}/${RM}/g" -e "s/{RC}/${RC}/g" -e "s/{RW}/${RW}/g"'
# COLORIZE Usage:
# command |${COLORIZE} ${LOWS} ${HIGHS} ${REVLOWS} ${REVHIGHS}
}

# diffDir shows diff content between two dirs
diffDir()
{
(($# < 2)) && echo "${W}diffDir ${C}<leftDir> <rightDir> ${c}[[[${C}miss|diff|same|all*${c}] [${C}uniq${c}]] [${C}resolv${c}]]${END}" && return 99
local showWhat=all
local UNIQ=false
local RESOLV=false
local uniqNames="cat"
local resolvPaths="cat"
local rightDirContent=/tmp/diffDir.$$.tmp

local leftDir=$1
local rightDir=$2
case $3 in
mis*) showWhat=miss ;;
dif*|siz*) showWhat=diff ;;
sam*) showWhat=same ;;
*)  showWhat=all ;;
esac
UNIQ=${4:+true}
RESOLV=${5:+true}

[ "$4" == "uniq" ] && uniqNames="awk '/~/ {n=split(\$2,libname,\".\");print libname[1]}'|sort|uniq"
[ "$5" == "resolv" ] && resolvPaths='while read _lib;do /bin/ls ${leftDir}/${_lib}.*;done'

ls -lqF ${rightDir}| awk 'NR>1 {if ($(NF-1) == "->") {printf "%s %s->%s\n",$5,$(NF-2),$NF} else {print $5,$NF}}' | sort -k 2 >${rightDirContent}
ls -lqF ${leftDir}| awk 'NR>1 {if ($(NF-1) == "->") {printf "%s %s->%s\n",$5,$(NF-2),$NF} else {print $5,$NF}}' | sort -k 2 | join -a1 -a2 -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.2,1.1,2.1,2.2 -e 0 - ${rightDirContent} |\
awk -v leftDir=${leftDir} -v rightDir=${rightDir} -v showWhat=${showWhat} '
function commas(d) {
  # http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_65.html
  d = d ""
  gsub(",","",d)
  point = index(d,".") - 1
  if (point < 0) point = length(d)
  while (point > 3) {
    point -= 3
    d = substr(d,1,point)","substr(d,point + 1)
  }
  return d
}
BEGIN {i=1;leftWidth=20;rightWidth=20;totalSizeLeft=0;totalSizeRight=0;sep="----------------------------------------------------------------"}
{
leftColor[i]="{w}";sign[i]="="
if ($2==$3) {if (showWhat!="all" && showWhat!="same") {next} else {leftColor[i]="{N}"}} else {leftColor[i]="{y}";sign[i]="~"}
if ($1 ~ "->") {leftColor[i]="{c}"}
leftName[i]=$1;leftSize[i]=$2;rightSize[i]=$3;rightName[i]=$4
middleColor[i]=leftColor[i]
if (leftName[i]=="0") {leftSize[i]="";leftName[i]="";middleColor[i]="{w}";sign[i]="#"} else {totalLeft++;totalSizeLeft+=leftSize[i]}
if (rightName[i]=="0") {rightSize[i]="";rightName[i]="";leftColor[i]=middleColor[i]="{w}";sign[i]="#"} else {totalRight++;totalSizeRight+=rightSize[i]}
if (showWhat=="same" && sign[i]!="=") {next}
if (showWhat=="miss" && sign[i]!="#") {next}
if (showWhat=="diff" && sign[i]!="~") {next}
if (length($1) > leftWidth) {leftWidth=length($1)}
if (length($4) > rightWidth) {rightWidth=length($4)}
if (leftName[i] ~ "->") {middleColor[i]="{c}"}
i++
}
END {
if (i==1) {print "identical"} else {
printf "%s %."leftWidth"s %.14s : %.14s %."rightWidth"s\n","{c}",sep,sep,sep,sep
printf "%s %"leftWidth"s %14s : %14s %-"rightWidth"s\n","{c}",leftDir,"","",rightDir
for (n=1; n<i; n++) {
  printf "%s %"leftWidth"s %14s %s%s %-14s %-"rightWidth"s\n",leftColor[n],leftName[n],commas(leftSize[n]),middleColor[n],sign[n],commas(rightSize[n]),rightName[n]
}
printf "%s %."leftWidth"s %.14s : %.14s %."rightWidth"s\n","{W}",sep,sep,sep,sep
printf "%s %"leftWidth"s %14s : %-14s %-"rightWidth"s{END}\n","{W}","total : "totalLeft,commas(totalSizeLeft),commas(totalSizeRight),totalRight
}
}' |\
${COLORIZE} ${LOWS} ${HIGHS} |\
eval ${uniqNames} |\
eval ${resolvPaths}

rm -f ${rightDirContent}
}
```