# Is there some tool for finding files in one directory but not in the other?

Tags: files, directory, diff

I would like to write a bash script to find those files in a directory but not in another directory.

Does the following script work? When does it not?

```
for i in "$1"/*; do
    f=$(basename $i);
    if [ ! -e "$2"/"$f" ]
    then
        echo $f
    fi
done
```

I heard `diff`  can find differences between the contents of two directories too. Can it also solve the same task?

Or some other tool?

Thanks.

Comment: More about diff for symmetric task: https://serverfault.com/questions/177001/find-files-in-one-directory-not-in-another

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/compare-files-that-are-in-directory-1-but-not-directory-2

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use `diff` for that purpose. It's as simple as:

```
diff -rq dir1 dir2
```

The `-r` option tells `diff` to recurse into sub-directories as well. The `-q` option tells `diff` to only report when files differ.

These are the two options I typically use when I want to find out which files are in `dir1`, but not in `dir2`, and vice versa. (You can also drop the `-r` parameter if you do not want to recurse into sub-directories, but only consider the immediate contents of the two directories.)

Note that this will show you both files that exist in `dir1` but not in `dir2`, as well as files that exist in `dir2`, but not in `dir1`, e.g.:

```
$ diff -rq /tmp/dir1/ /tmp/dir2/
Only in /tmp/dir1/: file1
Only in /tmp/dir2/: file2
Only in /tmp/dir2/: file3
```

If you need only one of the directions (e.g., files that are in `dir1` but not in `dir2`) and get a list of the filenames only (without the "Only in ..." clutter), you could certainly attempt to massage `diff`'s output using `grep`, `sed`, `awk` and the like, but in that case you're better off not using `diff` in the first place and use Stéphane Chazelas's solution instead.

Comment: Thanks. It is more convenient  in a single direction. But it is nice to know what diff can do at the best.

Comment: I assumed so, I only wanted to add an answer to the specific question: "Can diff be used for this task?". :-) Do note, however, that Stéphane's solution will not work recursively. So if you want to compare directories recursively, you'd need a more involved solution.

Comment: Note that `-q` is not a standard option.

Comment: Note that some `diff` implementations will follow symlinks to directories when recursing (note that the recursion was not asked for).

Comment: Note that it will also look for (and report) differences in the content of the files, so it does a lot more than comparing file names. If you run it after `truncate -s1T dir{1,2}/file`, it will take a while to complete.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas can `diff` be used on two directories? I am only interested in the contents of two directories, not the contents of the files or directories (no recursion) under the directories.

Comment: @Tim, not portably, nor reliably, I wouldn't go there, it's not been designed for that. `comm` was designed for that.

Answer (score 5):

If your file names don't contain newline characters, you can do:

```
(export LC_ALL=C; comm -23 <(ls -A dir1) <(ls -A dir2))
```

to find out which of the files in `dir1` are not found in `dir2`.

For arbitrary file names, you can use the array subtraction feature of `zsh`:

```
dir1_files=(dir1/*(DN:t)) dir2_files=(dir2/*(DN:t))
dir1_and_not_dir2_files=(${dir1_files:|dir2_files})
```

(change `*` to `**/*` for recursive list of files)

Or with bash4.4+ and recent versions of GNU utilities:

```
readarray -td '' dir1_and_not_dir2_files < <(
  export LC_ALL=C
  shopt -s nullglob  dotglob
  comm -z23 <(printf '%s\0' dir1/* | cut -zd/ -f2-) \
            <(printf '%s\0' dir2/* | cut -zd/ -f2-)
)
```

(use the `globstar` option and replace `*` with `**` for a recursive list).

The `LC_ALL=C` is needed for at least two reasons:

- filenames can contain any sequence of bytes (except 0 or the value for `/` (0x2F on ASCII-based systems)), while `comm` is a *text* utility, so with a behaviour unspecified for those sequences of bytes that don't format valid characters. In the C locale, all characters are single-byte and all bytes are valid characters (though possibly undefined), sp any file name is valid text (also considering that the maximum file name length is generally significantly smaller than the maximum text line length).
- more importantly, `comm` expects a sorted input, but in some locales, some characters have undefined sort order or sort the same as others which would confuse `comm`. For instance, on a GNU system in a en_GB.UTF-8 locale:

  ```
    $ ls dir1 dir2
    dir1:
          

    dir2:
          
    $ locale                     
    LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
    LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
    LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
    [...]
    $ comm -23 <(ls -A dir1) <(ls -A dir2) 
    $ (export LC_ALL=C; comm -23 <(ls -A dir1) <(ls -A dir2))
  ```

Those are mathematical letters whose order is not defined in GNU locales, so in the `en_GB.UTF-8` locales, as far as `comm` is concerned (or the sorting done by `ls`, see how I got     but I could just as well have gotten    ), those letters are the same, so `dir1` and `dir2` appear to contain the same files.

While in the C locale, `comm` and `ls` see one character for each of the byte of the encoding of those UTF-8 characters and the sorting is based on byte value, so all file names are different (except for , actually seen as four undefined characters with byte values 0xf0 0x9d 0x90 0x82, seen in both directories).

---

Your approach, with `basename $i` fixed to `basename -- "$i"` and `echo $f` fixed to `printf '%s\n' "$f"` would work except for file names that end in newline characters, but there are subtle differences in semantic:

Globs expand to directory entries. The shell doesn't need search access to directories to expand globs in them.

`"$1"/*` will expand to all the directory entries in `"$1"` that don't start with `.` (the hidden ones).

While the `[ -e "dir2/$f" ]` doesn't care at all about directory entries (it will succeeded even if you don't have read access to `dir2` as long as you have *search* access), it attempts a `stat()` system call on the file. You will see a difference if you don't have search permissions on `dir2` or for instance for symlink files whose target doesn't exist or is not reachable. For instance:

```
 ln -s /var/spool/cron/crontab/root dir2/root-crontab
 [ -e dir2/root-crontab ]
```

Would return false if run as a mere user (as you don't have read access to `/var/spool/cron/crontab`), but may return true if run as root if `root` has a crontab.

See also:

```
[ -e "dir2/$f" ] || [ -L "$dir2/$f" ]
```

to test whether `dir2/$f` exist or is a (broken/currently unresolvable by the current user at that path) symlink.

Comment: @derobert, yes, you do get that guarantee (unless you enabled some _nocaseglob_ or _numericglobsort_ option). Though as always, you need `LC_ALL=C` to be guaranteed a total order.

Comment: Indeed, and when I went and checked it seems sorted according to LC_COLLATE is a POSIX requirement.

Comment: Thanks. Will my original script work as well as your scripts?

Comment: Question: In the first solution, wouldn't `-A1` be preferable over `-A`, since otherwise multiple files might get listed in a single line?

Comment: I was wondering why  the environment setting in `(export LC_ALL=C; comm -23 <(ls -A dir1) <(ls -A dir2))`,  instead of just `comm -23 <(ls -1 dir1) <(ls -1 dir2)`?

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa When piped, results from `ls` are listed 1 per line by default. `man ls` doesn't tell you, but `info ls` somehow does.

Comment: @Tim About `LC_ALL`, I dare quoting [this exaustive answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/315749) by Stéphane himself.

Comment: @Tim, see edit for both your questions.